# MySQL Installation problem in wsl2 ubuntu 22.04

Tags: mysql, 22.04, windows-subsystem-for-linux

I'm using wsl2 in windows 10 pro. I try a lot to install mysql but I've gotten this error evry time.
I try to uninstall and install again with these command:

```
    sudo service mysql stop
    sudo apt purge mysql-server mysql-client mysql-common
    sudo rm -rf /etc/mysql /var/lib/mysql /var/log/mysql
    sudo apt autoremove
    sudo apt autoclean
```

and again install it.

and I got this error

```
Unpacking mysql-server (8.0.29-0ubuntu0.22.04.3) ...
Setting up mysql-client-8.0 (8.0.29-0ubuntu0.22.04.3) ...
Setting up mysql-server-8.0 (8.0.29-0ubuntu0.22.04.3) ...
invoke-rc.d: could not determine current runlevel
 * Stopping MySQL database server mysqld                        [ OK ]
update-alternatives: using /etc/mysql/mysql.cnf to provide /etc/mysql/my.cnf (my.cnf) in auto mode
Renaming removed key_buffer and myisam-recover options (if present)
mysqld will log errors to /var/log/mysql/error.log
mysqld is running as pid 4602
dpkg: error processing package mysql-server-8.0 (--configure):
 installed mysql-server-8.0 package post-installation script subprocess returned error exit status 1
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                                   dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-8.0; however:
  Package mysql-server-8.0 is not configured yet.

dpkg: error processing package mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
Processing triggers for man-db (2.10.2-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-8.0
 mysql-server
needrestart is being skipped since dpkg has failed
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would like to say that @Ashish Thakur's comment helped me. I had previously installed MySQL on my Windows, and then, again through WSL, I wanted to install it. So, after I stopped the service of the MYSQL instance in Windows Services, I could successfully install MySQL on Ubuntu (WSL).

Comment: Please don't add "thank you" as an answer. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://askubuntu.com/help/whats-reputation), you will be able to [vote up questions and answers](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/vote-up) that you found helpful. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/1339992)

Answer (score -1):

To install mySQL you need to ensure none of your other WSL environment already running it.
You can run mySQL in only one environment.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu and thanks for your contribution!  Can you provide more detail on your answer?  This seems very unlikely to be the problem that the OP is encountering given the error messages involved.  Also, it seems to me that it would be possible to run MySQL in more than one WSL distribution at a time, assuming you run the servers on different ports.  Note that I've tried it, but why would you think you can't?